# React render not not updating after setting state with Firebase data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to go into my Firebase database and save all groups that a user belongs to to an array then push that array to the components state and render a list of items accordingly but my render is not showing the items from the state.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setGroups();
}
setGroups(){
    const user = fire.default.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const dbRef = fire.default.database();
    const currentUserRef = dbRef.ref('users').child(user);
    const userGroups = currentUserRef.child('groups');
    const groupsRef = dbRef.ref('groups');
    const idArray = []
    const groupArray = []
    userGroups.on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(groupId => {
            idArray.push(groupId.val().groupId)
        })
        idArray.forEach(function(group, i) {
            groupsRef.child(idArray[i]).on('value', snap =>{
                let addGroup = {
                    id: snap.key,
                    name: snap.val().groupName,
                    description: snap.val().groupDescription,
                };
                groupArray.push(addGroup);
            })
            this.setState({
                hasGroups: true,
                groupsHold: groupArray,
            })
        }.bind(this))
    })
}
render(){
    console.log(this.state.hasGroups)
    if(this.state.hasGroups){
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.groupsHold.map((group, i) => 
                        <ListItem button
                        selected={this.state.selectedIndex === group}
                        onClick={event => this.handleListItemClick(event, group, i)}
                        key={`item-${group.id}`}>
                            <ListItemText primary={`${group.name}`} />
                        </ListItem>
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <p>You have no groups yet</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm setting the groups by going into my firebase and grabbing all groups that a user is part of from their user node then iterating through the 'groups' node and saving all groups that the user is a part of from that  to the state. I was expecting the render to reload on the new state but It is showing up blank. It's not showing the `<p>You have no groups yet</p>` so it recognizes that the state has groups but is is just showing an empty `<ul>`.

Comment: Do you have any error on your console?

Answer (score 0):

Calls to Firebase are asynchronous, but `setGroups` is not an `async` function as you have it written. I think your problem will be fixed if you make `setGroups` an `async` function and `await` your call to `userGroups.on('value', () => {})` inside of it.

Currently, your component is setting state when `groupsArray` is empty. So even though `this.state.hasGroups` is true, there are no groups to render!